# Google Cloud Run randomly spiking requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, hasura

I've deployed two Hasura instances via Cloud Run, but have been getting randomly spiking requests periodically for one of the containers. As far as I can see, this is not being initiated by any of our frontends, and the spikes look irregular. Weirdly enough, this issue is only happening on one of our instances.

Getting the following messages for each request:

#1:

```
{
  "insertId": "x",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "type": "webhook-log",
    "detail": {
      "http_error": null,
      "response": null,
      "message": null,
      "method": "GET",
      "status_code": 200,
      "url": "x/auth"
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-08-26T22:35:40.857+0000",
    "level": "info"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "service_name": "x",
      "configuration_name": "x",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "x",
      "revision_name": "x"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-08-26T22:35:41.839935Z",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "x"
  },
  "logName": "x",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-08-26T22:35:42.002274277Z"
}
```

#2:

```
{
  "insertId": "x",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "timestamp": "2021-08-26T22:35:40.857+0000",
    "detail": {
      "user_vars": null,
      "event": {
        "type": "accepted"
      },
      "connection_info": {
        "msg": null,
        "token_expiry": null,
        "websocket_id": "x"
      }
    },
    "level": "info",
    "type": "websocket-log"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "x",
      "revision_name": "x",
      "service_name": "x",
      "configuration_name": "x",
      "location": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-08-26T22:35:41.839957Z",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "x"
  },
  "logName": "x",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-08-26T22:35:42.002274277Z"
}
```

Drawing a blank right now as to what's going on. Any advice is helpful!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Question: you mentioned 2 hasura instances - are they for different applications and connected to different dbs? Hasura is: 1.3.x, 2.0, Hasura Cloud ? Databases are postgresql or something other possible in hasura 2.0 ?

Comment: I didn't catch the errors in your log trace...

Comment: Sorry @guillaumeblaquiere -- edited.

Thanks @AlexYu!! They are indeed for different applications and connected to different DBs. I'm working with Hasura v2.0.1, and using postgres

Comment: Can you first clarify what does each of your service do? And which of these two services encounter the randomly spiking requests?

Comment: It looks like it's happening on both services now. Getting a bunch of requests periodically.  3.02/s ATM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Turns out it was a few open WebSocket connections from users keeping their browser tab open.

Lesson learned!

Comment: So: websocket connections were from subscriptions - right? And those spikes of activity was generated by subscriptions - was that so?

Comment: yep that's it! @AlexYu